# Get second highest salary in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, correlated-subquery

Getting Connection Lost in coorelated queries.

```
select emp_no,salary
from salaries e 
where 2 = 
    (select count(distinct salary) from salaries p where p.salary>e.salary);
```

I tried this to get second highest salary but its giving me sql connection lost every time. All other queries are working fine except this one.

I m using sql workbench.

**Attached:**
[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgIyy.png)

Comment: Telling us the database is SQL Workbench is a bit like telling us what make car you drive based on the brand logo shown on the dashboard radio. Fine for some, but alarming from your mechanic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the connection has a 30 second time out, and the inefficient query is taking too long. This way is **much faster**, and should finish before the timeout:

```
SELECT emp_no, salary
FROM
(
    select emp_no,salary,row_number() over (order by salary desc) rn
    from salaries e  
) t
WHERE rn = 2
```

Eventually, if MySQL properly implements the ANSI `QUALIFY` keyword this might need even less code and run even a little faster.

Comment: When there are multiple employees with the same salary, the query displays only one of them.

Comment: @slaakso If that matters, it's simple enough to swap out `row_number()` for `dense_rank()`

Comment: That would be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

It's a little convoluted, but you can avoid an `order by` like this:

```
select emp_no, salary
from salaries
where salary = (
  select max(salary)
  from salaries
  where salary != (
    select max(salary)
    from salaries
  )
)
```

Comment: For some reason, this performs better: `select i from integers where i=(select max(i) from integers where i < (select max(i) from integers));`   (changed `!=` to `<` )

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think your SQL is going to give you the result that you want but that’s a secondary issue. To solve the error just increase the timeout setting: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_net_read_timeout

Comment: And then wait, even longer that 30 seconds, for the error to show?  The best option is still to use the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option using `LIMIT` + `OFFSET` keyword:

```
SELECT emp_no,
       salary
FROM salaries
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

If you can have more than two records with the 2nd highest salary, [Joel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77165041/12492890) is more suitable, yet changing window function to `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.